# Extract the sub elements >=2 into another list and delete them from the nested list

Tags: python, algorithm

So I have a nested list

```
l = [[116, 125, 118], [119], [120, 121, 131, 123], [120, 121, 123, 111], [122, 117], [124, 125, 126, 127], [128, 115], [129, 115], [130], [133], [136, 139, 134,  131, 123], [138, 132, 135], [138, 141], [140, 142], [143], [144], [145, 137], [146], [147, 149]]
```

I want to extract the common elements if they are more than 2 and delete them from the list, so it would be something like this

```
l=  [[116, 125, 118],  [119],  [120, 121, 131, 123],  [111], [122, 117],  [124, 125, 126, 127],  [128, 115],  [129, 115],  [130],  [133],  [136, 139, 134],[138, 132, 135],  [138, 141],  [140, 142],  [143],  [144],  [145, 137],  [146],  [147, 149]]
```

Delete 2 elements 120, 121
Delete 2 elements 131, 123

I have a very big list that could be computationally heavy too

Comment: You want to delete only if it was in the previous element, or in total? Why isn't `115` deleted from `[129, 115]`?

Comment: What is the code that you tried?

Comment: it should be more than 1 element to be deleted, and no it should be deleted if it exists anywhere, but we keep the first time we had the 2 elements

Comment: the code I'm using only delete the common elements from the upcoming list, but do not go any further

Comment: why isn't 123 deleted from l[3]? I see it coming twice.

Comment: yeah true, I only put it afterwards but it should be deleted

Comment: I suggest using either a `dict` or a `collections.Counter` to maintain a count of the elements, and keep them or not depending on whether the current count is larger than 2 or not.

Comment: I m not sure how to keep them ? also that would mean I would delete one element

Comment: basically every number should come once in the nested list?

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty set and iterate through the nested list. If a number is not in set add it inside a new list and the set.

```
s = set()
new_l = []
for ele in l :
    temp = []
    for num in ele :
        if num not in s :
            s.add(num)
            temp.append(num)
    new_l.append(temp)
```

Comment: The question is maybe not very clear, but still - this just doesn't give the expected output...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't give the expected output that is mentioned in the question. But as I mentioned in the comments a mistake about 123 in l[3] I think there are more mistakes in the expected output